# MySQL query optimization

Tags: mysql

Is there any other way to optimize this query?

```
select c.* 
FROM companies AS c 
  JOIN users AS u USING(companyid) 
  JOIN jobs AS j USING(userid) 
  JOIN useraccounts AS ua USING(userid) 
WHERE j.jobid = 123;
```

Comment: One way would be to only select the columns you actually need!

Comment: Why are you joining in things but never selecting values from them? also you didn't say what table structures you have, what indexs are enabled, etc

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` indicate? Is it using indices? ... Do you have indices?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that proper indices have been creatted - it's always a first step of optimization of any query.
 
Irrespective of indices, one solution worth trying in this case is an antijoin:

```
select c.* 
FROM companies AS c 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM users AS u 
  JOIN jobs AS j USING(userid) 
  JOIN useraccounts AS ua USING(userid)
  WHERE u.companyid = c.companyid
    AND j.jobid = 123
) 
;
```

however this query lists only distinct companies while the original query may multiply the same company many times.